# PowerShell to search for string in all users folder and to add string if not exist

Tags: powershell, deployment

I am trying to write a script that will

1. Search for specific string in the file that is located in each user profile on C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Nextcloud\nextcloud.cfg
2. If the string

   ```
   "[BWLimit]","downloadLimit=250","uploadLimit=250","useDownloadLimit=1","useUploadLimit=1"
   ```

   exists the file should not be touched
3. If the string does not exists it should add it

What I did till now is that I made a script, using examples from this great site, that works BUT it only works when I trigger it locally. I need the script to work remotely (I use PDQ to push the script)

The script is as follows

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\users\$($env:USERNAME)\AppData\Roaming\Nextcloud\nextcloud.cfg"
$sites   = "[BWLimit]","downloadLimit=250","uploadLimit=250","useDownloadLimit=1","useUploadLimit=1"

if (!(Test-Path "C:\users\$($env:USERNAME)\AppData\Roaming\Nextcloud\nextcloud.cfg")) {
    New-Item -Path "C:\users\$($env:USERNAME)\AppData\Roaming\Nextcloud" -Name nextcloud.cfg -Type "file"
} else {
    foreach ($site in $sites) {
        if (-not ($content -contains $site)) {
            $site | Out-File "C:\users\$($env:USERNAME)\AppData\Roaming\Nextcloud\nextcloud.cfg" -Append -Encoding utf8
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "work remotely"? Remotely where? In what environment? How do you want to trigger it? Under which condition(s)?

Comment: I want it to executed on Windows 10 machines once it come online. There is a functionally in PDQ Deploy that can do that for me but when PDQ execute it nothing is happening.

Comment: @Milter77 - does ANY PART of the code work when PDQ runs it on a remote test system? have you added any logging to see at what point the script fails?

Comment: You should at least move the top line `$content = Get-Content ...` to the top of the `else {..}` block. Now you try to read the content and **after** that you test if the file exists or not..

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for answering. The problem is that there is no error. Deployment is successful on PDQ, but the file that script should change  is not changed. That is where I am stuck because I cannot find where it fails. Just to repeat, the same script triggered locally with Powershell ISE works without error. Maybe my approach was bad at the beginning. I need to make a script that will for every user examine if the string exists in nextcloud.cfg and if there is no string to add it.

Comment: @Milter77 - please try adding some logging - try adding `Start-Transcript` to the beginning & `Stop-Transcript` to the end of the script. ///// another thing to check - what account is PDQ using? it needs to run as a the "current user", not a system account, AND the user needs to be one of your actual users, not a PDQ account.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Thank you so much for both advises. Finally it works when I changed the setting to run as Logged user on PDQ instead of default deploy user. It was in front of me all time and just missed it. Big **thanks** problem is finally solved

Comment: @Milter77 - kool! you are most welcome ... and i am glad to have helped a bit. [*grin*]